# React boostrap carousel not working when using array.map function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a simple carousel using react Bootstap but it seems not to work. The code below doesn't work

```
function CarouselItem({ item }) {

 return (
   <Carousel.Item>
  <img
    className="d-block w-100"
    src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQom33pPRha3xPSmmGVI5zaqSiraDxb_KuMKvmIOnfQb3rbHZZKJ8wxRGttgjfDpQ3cKrQ&usqp=CAU"
    alt="First slide"
  />
  <Carousel.Caption>
    <h3>{`${item} slide label`}</h3>
    <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
  </Carousel.Caption>
</Carousel.Item>
 );
}

function App() {
    return (
     <div className="App">
  <Carousel>
    {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((item) => {
      return <CarouselItem key={item} item={item} />;
    })}
  </Carousel> 
</div>
 );
}
```

but this code works very fine. Is there a way i can make the first code work? Because I have to fetch data in the CarouselItem component for each item before i render it that is why I want to use the first approach.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
  {/**but this way works**/}
  <Carousel>
    {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((item) => {
      return (
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            className="d-block w-100"
            src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQom33pPRha3xPSmmGVI5zaqSiraDxb_KuMKvmIOnfQb3rbHZZKJ8wxRGttgjfDpQ3cKrQ&usqp=CAU"
            alt="First slide"
          />
          <Carousel.Caption>
            <h3>{`${item} slide label`}</h3>
            <p>
              Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.
            </p>
          </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
      );
    })}
  </Carousel> 
</div>
 );
}
```

you can find the sandbox code here [sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-playground-forked-ghwr7?file=/src/index.js:683-1622)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this would work

```
<Carousel>
 {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((item) => {
   return <Carousel.Item key={item}>{item}</Carousel.Item>;
 })}
</Carousel>
```

In [React-Bootstrap docs](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/carousel/#carousel-item-props) I cannot find property `item` for `<Carousel.Item />`, you must pass children instead.

Comment: @Idruskis it works but i don't see the images, i only see the item number.

Comment: You must add image inside `Carousel Item`, now you're just mapping numbers and trying to render a number. Try to create array of images and instead render them.

Comment: In your second example "that works" you use `<img />` inside `Carousel.Item`, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-playground-forked-seg19?file=/src/index.js) an example how you could do it

Comment: @Idruskis thanks but in my case, i will make a call to an api to get an image in  the CarouselItem component in a useEffect hook and get the data for that particular item. the numbers used can be represented as an id to make the api calls to with that particular id. that's how i want to do it but it doesn't work

Comment: Ok. So create your custom Image renderer component, pass `id` to it via props, fetch in useEffect and return the content. Use this custom component inside of Carousel.Item.

Comment: i see will try it and see how it goes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241688/discussion-between-moro-owusu-afriyie-and-ldruskis).